# Match by regular expression to string replace by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is like

> `5blog5sett5ings5[5slider5][5][5ima5ge5]`

I like to match any digit into second brackets from end by regular expression.

For this case, my target digit is `5` into `[5]`.

I like to select where before pattern like
`5blog5sett5ings5[5slider5][` and after pattern like `][5ima5ge5]`

I will use it for JavaScript string replace. Text can be different but the before and after patterns are like that.  [For better understanding see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYddn.png)

[image]

I tried something like

```
(?<=.+[.+?][)\d(?=][.+?])
```

but did not work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which programing language are you using?

Comment: Why do you think regular expressions are the answer here, instead of string replacements?

Comment: What replacement do you actually want to do?

Comment: I tried something like (?<=.+\[.+?\]\[)\d(?=\]\[.+?\]) but did not work.

Comment: If you just want to match the digit, try [`\d+(?=]\[[^\]]*]$)`](https://regex101.com/r/aldmnB/1)

Comment: My string is not alway same. I like to change digit by JavaScript. Like  
"blog-sett5ings[slider][5][image]".replace(/pattern/, 6);

Comment: Thanks @bobble bubble. Your solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if there `]` and one more `[` `]` ahead until end.

```
\d+(?=]\[[^\]]*]$)
```

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aldmnB/1/)

(be aware that lookbehind you tried is not available in js regex)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
\[(\d+)\][^\]]+]$
```

[Regex Demo & Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/MR1ujJ/2)

```js
var myString = "5blog5sett5ings5[5slider5][5][5ima5ge5]";
var myRegexp = /\[(\d+)\][^\]]+]$/mg;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Comment: The OP wants only the number 5 to be matched.

Comment: @horcrux it matches on group 1.

Comment: Sry, you are right, regex101 shows only the group 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
^.*\[(\d*)\]\[[^\]]*\]$
```

Where:

- `^` is the begin of the string
- `.*` means any  character
- `\[` and `\]` matches literal squared brackets
- `(\d*)` is what you want to match
- `[^\]]*` is the content of the last couple of brackets
- `$` is the end of the string

See an example:

```js
var str = "5blog5sett5ings5[5slider5][5][5ima5ge5]";
var res = str.match(/^.*\[(\d*)\]\[[^\]]*\]$/);
console.log(res[1])
```